# Users cannot logout because session is not deleted

Tags: joomla-2.5, login

I am using the core users component. Users after logging in are not able to logout, the logout button simple refreshes the page.

Joomla is not deleting entries from the `_session` table when a user logs out.

I have disabled extra registration plugins and also changed the session handler and ssl configuration without success. I've been clearing, optimizing and repairing session table.

Any one have ever heard or experienced this problem and can get me a clue?

Comment: "I have disabled extra registration plugins" did you by any chance disable/replace core user plugin, if so try enabling/restoring it.

Answer (score 3):

Just some thoughts:

This could be caused by adding some custom login/logout - Module and then deactivate it without changing the module on frontend back to joomla standard login/logout-Module. If the logout-Button doesnt log the user out, first check if it´s an issue with the logout-module or logout-menuitem. It´s probably not assigned to any Module/Komponent.

Try to add a new (eg hidden) menu-item "user manager"->"Login Form". It should have this link: index.php?option=com_users&view=login (Standard Joomla component). And try to login/logout through that page.

Try to add a new Module: "Module Manager-> Module Login" (Standard Joomla Module). And test with that.

Disable cache in "System->Konfiguration->System->Cache->OFF" while testing and clear cache.

Make sure that all the necessary User-Extensions are published: Eg. "Extensions->Manage->Filter: Select Folder Users->User - Joomla!" Can be deactivated